# How to custom a gson converter in retrofit 2.0?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I will init object in gson converter.

In retrofit 1.9, I rewrite GsonConverter like this:

```
public class MyGsonConverter extends GsonConverter {
        @Override
        public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
                    Object obj = super.fromBody(body, type);
                    if (obj instanceof User) {
                        ((User)obj).init();
                    }
                    return obj;
        }
}
```

RestAdapter setConverter(new MyGsonConverter(gson))

Now In Retrofit 2.0, It's not has GsonConverter, It's change to Converter.Factory.
It's can't return a object in method.

How can I do init my object in a converter in Retrofit 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the ConverterFactory instead of the Converter and supply your custom GsonResponseBodyConverter for it, based on the existing classes in retrofit-converter.

Probably there will be documentation on it:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1305

Meanwhile, you can modify these classes the same way as with the Converter:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/gson

If you could do it with the Converter, it shouldn't be that hard with the Factory.